# Controlling FPS of a loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a flash app where I load multiple swf's. But the problem is that they have different framerates (12/25/30). If I add 2 swf's they both play at 25fps. I found numerous topic about this but I can't get it to work (in AS3). Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how to make it working?

```
public class MainClass extends MovieClip 
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var request:URLRequest;

        var mcMedia:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

        MovieClip.prototype.setFrameRate = function(frameRate:Number)
        {
            var mc:MovieClip = this;
            if (mc.tweenFaster != null)
            {
                Timer(mc.tweenFaster).stop();
            }
            mc.tweenFaster = new Timer(1000/frameRate);
            mc.tweenFaster.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timelineFaster);
            mc.tweenFaster.start();

            function timelineFaster(event:TimerEvent = null)
            {               
                if (mc.currentFrame == mc.totalFrames)
                {
                    mc.tweenFaster.stop();
                    mc.gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    trace(mc.currentFrame);
                    mc.nextFrame();
                }                           

                event.updateAfterEvent();
            }
        }

        public function MainClass() 
        {
            configureListeners();
            request = new URLRequest("data/7/7.swf");

            try 
            {
                loader.load(request);
            } 
            catch (error:Error) 
            {
                trace("Unable to load requested document.");
            }
        }

        private function configureListeners():void 
        {           
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void 
        {
            loader.content.scaleX = 550/event.target.width;
            loader.content.scaleY = 400/event.target.height;
            mcMedia.addChild(loader);
            mcMedia.setFrameRate(12);
            addChild(mcMedia);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you not just creating all the swfs with the correct framerate to start with? or correcting the existing swfs framerate?

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but I cannot create or correct the existing SWF's frame rates because A.) there are THOUSANDS of them, and B.) they contain embedded video and audio synced to stream, and C.) certain external scripts are triggered at certain frame numbers, so it must play at original rate.  You see, I upgraded the main system from AS2 15-fps to AS3 60-fps.  Now I have all these AS2 15-fps that need to be loaded and played at 15fps, without affecting the main movie which plays at 60fps.  Currently, they're tripping the main movie to reduce its frame rate to 15-fps while they play.

Comment: Thanks for support all! The swf's I want to play are from 3rd parties, I don't have access to the code/animations. Due this problem I don't know if the swf are plain simple animations or if they have scripted events (let alone wat version of action script).

Answer (score 1):

In as3, if you're just looking to change the framerate, use stage.frameRate = 12; or whatever;

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate

In AS3, while you *can* use prototypes, you generally don't. I'd rewrite your setFrameRate function (which is badly named, shouldn't it be more.. tweenFaster, or matchFrameRate or something?)

I'd make a helper function like this:

```
package util{

//imports

public class TweenFasterMC extends MovieClip{

   public var mc:MovieClip;

   public function matchFrameRate(frameRate:Number):void
   {
                if (tweenFaster != null)
                {
                        Timer(mc.tweenFaster).stop();
                }
                tweenFaster = new Timer(1000/frameRate);
                tweenFaster.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timelineFaster);
                tweenFaster.start();

    }

    function timelineFaster(event:TimerEvent = null):void
    {                               
                        if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
                        {
                                tweenFaster.stop();
                                gotoAndStop(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                trace(currentFrame);
                                nextFrame();
                        }                                                       

                        event.updateAfterEvent();
    }

}
```

Also, clean up your event listeners, that strong timer event listener will cause a lot of problems if you have a lot of mc's your applying this functionality to.

Comment: I know of stage.frameRate but I can't use because I have 2 movieclips simulatneously, 1 orginal fps is 25 and the other one is 12. When i use the stage.frameRate both clips will run at 12 or 25.
Also this function doesn't change the playback of the movieclip. Still at the same framerate as the root swf (25fps). Also trace(currentFrame); only prints zeros

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You'd just need ever clip whose speed you wanted to control to extend this though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all MovieClips in one flash player instance (sharing the same 'stage') will run at the same speed - there is no way to have two clips running at different speeds. So to adjust the speed you have to resort to calling gotoAndStop() on all MovieClips in the loaded clip at the right time - that won't be fun.

Code along the lines that quoo is showing will only work if the loaded swf contains just 1 MovieClip (no nesting) as far as I can see.

Comment: I have a much larger flash program. I created a much smaller app with only the playback problem.

"So to adjust the speed you have to resort to calling gotoAndStop() on all MovieClips in the loaded clip"
This is not working for nested clips because trace(currentFrame);
 only prints zeros

Comment: In that case you probably have some nested movieclips in your swfs - the outer movieclip only has a single frame, and one of the inner movieclips contains the actual animation. If you don't have the original fla files it will be very hard to resolve your issue.

Comment: ... this is assuming you have flash files with animations done on the timeline, if the animation is scripted these solutions won't help at all.

Comment: My code was intended to be a base class for any movieclip whose speed you wanted to control.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the most likely reason why this wouldn't work is that it requires every clip you load to be a simple, completely non-dynamic animation that loops for ever. If the loaded content is that simple, why not just adjust it to look better at 30fps? (If it's extremely long, a JSFL script could automate the process of adding extra frames.) Alternately, if the content *isn't* that simple, then attempting to change its timing by calling `nextFrame` from elsewhere is not going to give you what you want.

With all that said, if you're sure this is what you want to do but you're getting 0 as a return for `currentFrame` in your loaded content, are you sure they are AS3 SWFs? If they aren't, AS3/AS2 interoperation is a hairy subject that will warrant reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real hassle, I've been scouring the net for an answer.   I have particles following  a path, and I want to change the speed that these particles follow the path dynamically, without changing the whole movie.   just the particles movie clip.

I've tried greensock, but, that doesn't really work like i need..  i'd think there would be something that you can change dynamically for each mc, but, no dice.

the stage.frameset is only for the whole movie... argggggggg.....  sucks..